# Outlook Add-In getting body content using Typescript

Tags: typescript, outlook-web-addins

I'm pretty new to TypeScript and I'm in the process of building an Outlook Add-In that send the contents of an email to a database, through an API. I've managed to successfully get and send up the `subject`, `to`, `cc` and `from`.

But getting the body of the email or "`description`" is causing me problems. The problem has something to do with the function running before it receives a "`success`" so the `if` statement is never `true`. Ive tried using "`await`" but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```js
const getBodyDescription = async () => {
  let emailBody = await item.body;
  emailBody.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      getEmailDataToSend.description = asyncResult.value;
      console.log("body hit");
    } else {
      console.log("body fail");
    }
  });
  console.log("passed method");
}
```

Comment: if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) is looks wrong in the code mentioned above . This is checking for not Success case . Is it expected here??